# ios - Which side should perform RNG calculations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, random, p2p

I'm writing a game for iOS that pits two players (peer-to-peer) against each other.  I'm using GameKit for things like PeerPickerController, and NSCoding protocol for archiving and sending game state.  However, I'm wondering if there is some design pattern for games that require an RNG -- like dice rolls for damage, random parameters, event occurrence, etc.

Specifically, in a turn-based game, in which two players submit their moves, and then the moves are executed, which side should be performing the RNG calculations and transmitting the results to the other?  Is it arbitrary (like compare the two player UUIDs, and higher one gets the responsibility)?  Or is there a design pattern that divides the task between the two players in a preconceived fashion?

The main issues here are (1.) ensuring that the same random number is generated for both sides for the same move, and (2.) not doing so in advance because if things are killed during the turn execution, or attacks are redirected after some of the calculations have finished, then there may not be a need to do some calculations, and others may be affected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say in a peer-to-peer game it doesn't matter, unless one can be considered the host. Because there is a general rule with host-client applications: *never trust the client*. That is, if you had a server the critical calculations should be done there or at least get validated on the server to protect against cheating or transmission errors.

But if you have two equal peers the side that does the calculation probably doesn't matter much as both have to trust each other. But I would avoid trying to the same RNG calculations on both sides.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I eventually want to move to server, but I am currently just testing out initially with local p2p. The interesting thing is I want to just compute results for a whole list of moves all at once, to reduce number of times transmission/reception is necessary, but sometimes results of one affect execution of another midway through the list. It's not a real-time game, perse, but moves both players selected are intertwined based on speed parameters, so not everything is predictable or predetermined from the moment both players submit their moves.

Answer (score 0):

Either you select one of the devices to be the host, making all the calculations on that machine. It's arbitrary, although if the calculations are demanding, try to pick the newest device. The other  (simpler) option is having the device performing the move do the calculations.

Obviously it it a bit of a security risk but then again you can never be safe from cheaters with P2P gaming.